# jQuery clearTimeout isn't working?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, clearinterval

I am trying to clear this timeout so it restarts when this button has been clicked, however it isn't working :\

```
var confirmAlbumDelete;
$("body").on("click", ".upload-result-wrapper .top-details .delete", function(){

    clearTimeout(confirmAlbumDelete);

    $this = $(this);
    $this.text("Yes, Delete Album").addClass("confirm-delete");

    confirmAblumDelete = setTimeout(function(){$this.text("Delete Album").removeClass("confirm-delete")},10000);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled the variable name:

```
confirmAblumDelete = setTimeout
        ^^
```

Comment: Oh my god, I checked like 5 times too, >.>.. Thanks.. haha.

Comment: @DylanCross to avoid that kind of error, consider using a linting tool, like [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: Yeah, I use Dreamweaver CS 5.5 for my coding environment, only because I've used it from the day I got into programming and never wanted to switch, so Idk if there is anyway to enable that in it or not. would be helpful, as I'm always making silly mistakes like this in javascript or php